# How to move the mouse pointer visually in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to move the mouse pointer visually to a web element. I have tried the following code, but it does not seem to work. The mouse pointer remains in the same place.

```
actionChains = ActionChains(driver) 
actionChains.move_to_element(link).perform()
```

Comment: please share html code of webpage

Comment: You probably won't see the mouse cursor move. Do you get hover behavior on the element you moved to? That's the more interesting question...

Comment: @jeffc yes i do get the hover behaviour, In my scenario(desktop Sharing scenario) when the mouse pointer is moved in screen1 then a virtual pointer is moved to the particular point in the screen2., This doesn't happen when hover operation is performed internally without moving the mouse pointer.

Comment: So you are getting the hover behavior... why does it matter if you see the mouse move?

Comment: Only when the pointer moves in the screen 1 then the virtual (or dummy) pointer moves in the screen 2. Actually the hover operation is done to validate this scenario. Can you suggest any other method?