# How to VISUALLY move the mouse cursor to a specific position via Selenium VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

please do not block me. I found similar question in this link:
[How to move the mouse pointer visually in selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461820/how-to-move-the-mouse-pointer-visually-in-selenium-python)
but there was no answer. So I decided to ask again.

How may I VISUALLY move the mouse cursor to a specific position via Selenium in VBA Excel?

This is the code I tried. I want to move the cursor to 5,10. But the mouse cursor doesn't move visually.

```
Sub VisuallyCursorMove()
    dim Driver as Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Set Driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Driver.Start
    Driver.Get "http://www.yahoo.com"
    Driver.Actions.MoveByOffset(5, 10).Perform
End Sub
```

If you are going to ask me that what does it matter to see visually the cursor, I should answer that it is because I am using Magnifier. I should move the mouse to any place to see that in the magnifier window. So I want every mouse actions in my Selenium project, able to see in magnifier window.

Comment: would it be feasible to use a DLL for this? - `SetCursorPos(x, y)` from "user32.dll" comes to mind

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII
Actually no. Because I need to do it in the browser. So if I use the command from user32, it will brings to the coordinates (5,10) of the screen, not the browser.

Comment: `GetCursorPos()`? - I see that in your example you use Offset, so Getting the current Cursor Pos and using those coordinates as a baseline is basically what you are trying to do, no? - If you were actually trying to set absolute Pos and not relative to the current Pos, you could still use smth. like `GetWindowRect()` which would give you the coordinates of your browser window, and from there you could set the CursorPos relative to that window (since you know where it is on the screeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar in the past, so I'll post some code you can try. I haven't tested it now, so there might be some bugs/issues with it. Also, a bunch of the declared API functions are not used in this snippet, I had no time to remove them now.

If this `Sub` doesn't perfectly fit your needs it should be easy to adapt, you could also move the mouse to a position defined by `WebDriverRECT.right - offsetX` and `WebDriverRECT.bottom -offsetY`...

Also, you can experiment with `oWebDriver.Window.Position.x`,  `oWebDriver.Window.Position.y`, `oWebDriver.Window.Size.Width` and `oWebDriver.Window.Size.Height`, I exclusively used Windows API functions for consistency in the scaling.

```vb
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliSeconds As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As PointAPI) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, lpRect As RECT) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal msg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Any, ByVal fuFlags As Long, ByVal uTimeout As Long, lpdwResult As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Boolean
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If
#Else
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "sleep" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
    Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As PointAPI) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Any, ByVal fuFlags As Long, ByVal uTimeout As Long, lpdwResult As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Type PointAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type RECT
    left As Long
    top As Long
    right As Long
    bottom As Long
End Type

Private Sub MoveMouseToWebDriverPos(ByVal oWebDriver As Object, _
                                    ByVal posX As Long, _
                                    ByVal posY As Long)
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim WebDriverHwnd As LongPtr
    Dim dlgHwnd As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim WebDriverHwnd As Long
    Dim dlgHwnd As Long
#End If

    WebDriverHwnd = FindTopLevelWindow(oWebDriver.Title, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
    
    'Get Edge window position and dimensions:
    'Note: It is necessary to use the Windows API Functions here,
    'as the Selenium internal ones:
    'oWebDriver.Window.Position.x, oWebDriver.Window.Position.y,
    'oWebDriver.Window.Size.Width and oWebDriver.Window.Size.Height
    'seem to use different scaling and return different (wrong) values
    Dim WebDriverRECT As RECT: GetWindowRect WebDriverHwnd, WebDriverRECT

    'If you want to rturn cursor to original position afterwards, cache pos here
    'Dim CachedPos As PointAPI: GetCursorPos CachedPos

    SetCursorPos WebDriverRECT.left + posX, WebDriverRECT.top + posY

    'If you want to click:
'    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
'    Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
'    Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
'    Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
    'mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
    'mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
    
    'If you want to rturn cursor to original position after some action
    'SetCursorPos CachedPos.X, CachedPos.y
End Sub

#If VBA7 Then
Private Function FindTopLevelWindow(partOfTitleStr As String, _
                          Optional className As String = "§$%³") As LongPtr
#Else
Private Function FindTopLevelWindow(partOfTitleStr As String, _
                           Optional className As String = "§$%³") As Long
#End If
    Const GW_CHILD = 5
    Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
    Dim tLen As Long
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    
    FindTopLevelWindow = GetWindow(GetDesktopWindow(), GW_CHILD)
    
    Do While FindTopLevelWindow <> 0
        tLen = GetWindowTextLength(FindTopLevelWindow)
        Dim wname As String: wname = Space(tLen)
    
        GetWindowText FindTopLevelWindow, wname, tLen
        
        If InStr(1, wname, partOfTitleStr) > 0 Then
            If className <> "§$%³" Then
                Dim tClassName As String: tClassName = Space(256)
                GetClassName FindTopLevelWindow, tClassName, Len(tClassName)
                
                'Null termination has to be removed:
                If className = left(Trim(tClassName), Len(Trim(tClassName)) - 1) Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        FindTopLevelWindow = GetWindow(FindTopLevelWindow, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 10 = 0 Then DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

Edit:

As requested in your comment, to use this code, just call the `Sub` I provided in your code:

```vb
Sub VisuallyCursorMove()
    dim Driver as Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Set Driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Driver.Start
    Driver.Get "http://www.yahoo.com"
    
    'The following moves the mouse cursor to the position 57 pixels from the top
    'and 57 pixels from the left of your WebDriver window, so probably somewhere
    'around the top left corner of the window.
    MoveMouseToWebDriverPos(Driver, 57, 57)
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, what a big code! Thanks a lot!
But how can I use this in my code? I mean the code I wrote in the main question?

Comment: @Sherlock_Holmes, I added some clarification to the bottom of my post, I hope this helps! Just experiment with the pixel values until the cursor gets moved to the correct position.

Comment: I changed rom VBA to VB.NET. So could you please kindly guide me that how may I use the code in vb.net ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sherlock_Holmes, Unfortunately, VB.NET is a very different language, and converting this code would be just as much work for me as it would be for you, so I can not help you with that.